# Pulling sentences with combinations of keywords in python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the string

```
'apples are red. this apple is green. pears are sometimes red, but not usually. pears are green. apples are yummy. lizards are green.'
```

and I want to use regular expressions to pull the sentences in that string that mention either apple or pear first and then its color, red or green. So I basically want a list returned that has:

```
["apples are red.", "this apple is green.", "pears are sometimes red, but not usually.", pears are green."]
```

I can pull a regular expression for just apples and pears or green and red with something like

```
re.findall(r'([^.]*?apple[^.]*|[^.]*?pear[^.]*)', string)
```

and

```
re.findall(r'([^.]*?red[^.]*|[^.]*?green[^.]*)', string)
```

but how do I put these two together when I want the fruit (apple/pear) to come first in the string followed by the color and some later point in the sentence?

Comment: Looks for the sentences that are matched by both calls to findall (intersection). They will be the sentences that match both criteria.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: That won't ensure that one element matches before the other, though.

Comment: @TimPietzcker very true.

Comment: honestly your code will be more readable and maintainable if you separate your operations.  Split your string into sentences in one step, and then filter the ones that match `(apple|pear).*(red|green)` in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parentheses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to group sub-expressions:

```
re.findall(r"[^.]*\b(?:apple|pear)[^.]*\b(?:red|green)\b[^.]*\.", string)
```

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'apples are red. this apple is green. pears are sometimes red, but not usually. pears are green. apples are yummy. lizards are green.'
>>> re.findall(r"[^.]*\b(?:apple|pear)[^.]*\b(?:red|green)\b[^.]*\.", a)
['apples are red.', ' this apple is green.', 
 ' pears are sometimes red, but not usually.', ' pears are green.']
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `(?:^|\b)(?=[^.]*(?:apple|pear)[^.]*(?:red|green))([^.]+\.)` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wN5jJ8)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read about [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) (Natural Language Tool Kit). It's a python package for text processing